# Amplifying power of two matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Studying dynamic systems I've stumbled upon a doubt.
I have the initial response of two discrete systems:
$x_A(k)=A^kx_0$ and $x_B(k)=B^kx_0$, with A and B square matrices.
Now, $||A||<||B||$.
I'm interested in comparing the sum of components of $x_A$ and $x_B$.
I found pretty obvious (but probably wrong!) that $$\sum\limits_{i=1}^n {x_A}_i < \sum\limits_{i=1}^n {x_B}_i$$. Or at least I think that this is true for $k -> \infty$.

Assumptions: matrix norm 1 is used. A,B matrix are made of positive (or zero) scalars, x0 > 0.

But..is it true? Why?

Comment: Might be interesting for you: There is a beautiful bound on the sum of entries of the power of nonnegative matrices proved in the book Matrix analysis of Horn and Johnson 2nd edition. (Corollary 8.1.33)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not true. Take
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\0 & 1\end{bmatrix}, \quad B=\begin{bmatrix}1 & -1\\-1 & 1\end{bmatrix},\quad x_0=\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Then $\|A\|=1<\|B\|=2$, but $\sum x_A=1>\sum x_B=0$ for all $k$.

**Update:** take
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\0 & 1\end{bmatrix}, \quad B=\begin{bmatrix}\frac12 & 1\\0 & \frac12\end{bmatrix},\quad x_0=\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Then $\|A\|_1=1<\|B\|_1=1.5$, however, $\sum x_A=2$ for all $k$ while $x_B\to 0$ since $B$ is stable, so $\sum x_B\to 0<2$ when $k\to +\infty$. The norms are too crude measures. The asymptotics of $x_A$ and $x_B$ depends more on the spectral radii of $A$ and $B$. Moreover, the corresponding part of $x$ (the sum) must be [observable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observability).

Comment: what if all the elements of the matrix are positive? in addition, if we use matrix norm 1 your confutation doesn't hold...

Comment: @Surferonthefall Not true, for example, for negative $x_0$. Notation $\|\cdot\|$ is by default the spectral norm. It would be easier to answer if you put all assumptions in the question.

Comment: you're right, sorry. updated question.

Comment: @Surferonthefall Still not true (see the update).